# Ruby algorithm to determine valid HTML structure

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have to as input data an array with hashes, each hash is description of an html tag (open and end position in the text and type of the tag). I need to generate another array where tags are put in order.

For example:

```
input = [
         {start_p: 0, end_p: 100, start_t: '<p>', end_t: '</p>'},
         {start_p: 10, end_p: 50, start_t: '<p>', end_t: '</p>'},
         {start_p: 0, end_p: 100, start_t: '<span>', end_t: '</span>'},
         {start_p: 20, end_p: 30, start_t: '<em>', end_t: '</em>'},
         {start_p: 40, end_p: 50, start_t: '<em>', end_t: '</em>'},
         {start_p: 50, end_p: 60, start_t: '<em>', end_t: '</em>'},
         {start_p: 70, end_p: 80, start_t: '<em>', end_t: '</em>'},
         {start_p: 8, end_p: 99, start_t: '<strong>', end_t: '</strong>'}
        ]

expected_output: [<p><span><strong><p><em></em><em></em></p><em></em><em></em></strong></span></p>]
```

instead of just tags in output, each tag should be a Hash with position and tag, like:

```
     {position: 0, tag: '<p>'}
```

The most important thing it to be ordered in right order, respecting HTML rules of not having intersecting tags (if more than one tags are ending on the same position, the one opened last should go first, if one ends and other opens on the same position, end will be first, etc).

This is part of a legacy system and input and output can't be changed at the moment. Also, the input can be very big (hundreds of thousands of elements)

Any better solution than just brute force recursive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.group_by { |h| h[:start_p] }.
      values.
      flat_map do |a|
        x = 1.0
        a.flat_map do |h|
          x /= 2.0
          [[h[:start_p] += x, h[:start_t]], [h[:end_p] -= x, h[:end_t]]]
        end
      end.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last).join
#=> "<span><p><strong><p><em></em><em></p></em><em></em><em></em></strong></p></span>"
```

The steps are as follows.

```
b = input.group_by { |h| h[:start_p] }
  #=> { 0=>[{:start_p=>0, :end_p=>100, :start_t=>"<p>", :end_t=>"</p>"},
  #        {:start_p=>0, :end_p=>100, :start_t=>"<span>", :end_t=>"</span>"}],
  #    10=>[{:start_p=>10, :end_p=>50, :start_t=>"<p>", :end_t=>"</p>"}],
  #    20=>[{:start_p=>20, :end_p=>30, :start_t=>"<em>", :end_t=>"</em>"}],
  #    40=>[{:start_p=>40, :end_p=>50, :start_t=>"<em>", :end_t=>"</em>"}],
  #    50=>[{:start_p=>50, :end_p=>60, :start_t=>"<em>", :end_t=>"</em>"}],
  #    70=>[{:start_p=>70, :end_p=>80, :start_t=>"<em>", :end_t=>"</em>"}],
  #     8=>[{:start_p=> 8, :end_p=>99, :start_t=>"<strong>", :end_t=>"</strong>"}]}
c = b.values
  #=> [[{:start_p=>0, :end_p=>100, :start_t=>"<p>", :end_t=>"</p>"},
  #     {:start_p=>0, :end_p=>100, :start_t=>"<span>", :end_t=>"</span>"}],
  #    [{:start_p=>10, :end_p=>50, :start_t=>"<p>", :end_t=>"</p>"}],
  #   ...
  #    [{:start_p=>8, :end_p=>99, :start_t=>"<strong>", :end_t=>"</strong>"}]]
d = c.flat_map do |a|
      x = 1.0
      a.flat_map do |h|
        x /= 2.0
        [[h[:start_p] += x, h[:start_t]], [h[:end_p] -= x, h[:end_t]]]
      end
    end
  #=> [[0.5, "<p>"], [99.5, "</p>"], [0.25, "<span>"], [99.75, "</span>"],
  #    [10.5, "<p>"], [49.5, "</p>"], [20.5, "<em>"], [29.5, "</em>"],
  #    [40.5, "<em>"], [49.5, "</em>"], [50.5, "<em>"], [59.5, "</em>"],
  #    [70.5, "<em>"], [79.5, "</em>"], [8.5, "<strong>"], [98.5, "</strong>"]]
```

The first four element of `d` (tuples) are the most important to understanding the approach I've taken.

```
e = d.sort_by(&:first)
  #=> [[0.25, "<span>"], [0.5, "<p>"], [8.5, "<strong>"], [10.5, "<p>"],
  #    [20.5, "<em>"], [29.5, "</em>"], [40.5, "<em>"], [49.5, "</p>"],
  #    [49.5, "</em>"], [50.5, "<em>"], [59.5, "</em>"], [70.5, "<em>"],
  #    [79.5, "</em>"], [98.5, "</strong>"], [99.5, "</p>"], [99.75, "</span>"]]

f = e.map(&:last)
  #=> ["<span>", "<p>", "<strong>", "<p>", "<em>", "</em>", "<em>", "</p>",
  #    "</em>", "<em>", "</em>", "<em>", "</em>", "</strong>", "</p>", "</span>"]
f.join
  #=> "<span><p><strong><p><em></em><em></p></em><em></em><em></em></strong></p></span>"
```

I will elaborate the calculation of `d` above if requested to do so.

Comment: Admission: I don't know HTML. (Stop snickering, please.) I've assumed that if two or more start tags are to be at the same location the corresponding end tags will also be at the same location, and that the order of the start tags is unimportant, but the order the end tags must be in reverse order of the start tags. Please let me know if my assumption is correct, so that I can delete my answer if I'm wrong.

Comment: order of start tags is important. (for example are tags that can't be contained in certain tags or can't contain certain tags), but you are right, is not the scope of this algorithm to determine that, so we can assume that starting and ending tags at same position will have a random order of starting tags.

Comment: Thanks, @Eduard. Since you said nothing to the contrary, I assume I am correct that (for the purpose of the question) tags with the same start position will have the same end position.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I did some tests that passed, nice idea to use a float for sorting. Regarding your question, not all tags with same start position will have same end position (actually 90% of the cases will not have the same end), but when will have, the right order of the start tags can't be set and is not the scope of this question.

Comment: I found a usecase when it is failing: 
[{start_p: 0, end_p: 121, start_t: '<span>', end_t: '</span>'},
    {start_p: 121, end_p: 134, start_t: '<b>', end_t: '</b>'},
    {start_p: 134, end_p: 147, start_t: '<span>', end_t: '</span>'},
    {start_p: 138, end_p: 147, start_t: '<strong>', end_t: '</strong>'},
    {start_p: 147, end_p: 418, start_t: '<span>', end_t: '</span>'}]
span ending at 147 is closed before strong ending at same position

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by *brute force recursive*, but this can be done with `sort_by` and `map`. It's a matter of making your `sort_by` correct to achieve your required HTML rules.

```
output = input.sort_by { |hsh| hsh[:start_p] }.map{|x| x.slice(:start_p, :start_t)}
output.each do |h|
  h[:position] = h.delete(:start_p)  
  h[:tag] = h.delete(:start_t)  
end
```

Monkey patching slice method.

```
module MyExtension
  module Hash 
    def slice(*keys)
      ::Hash[[keys, self.values_at(*keys)].transpose]
    end
  end
end
Hash.include MyExtension::Hash
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, that's a Rails helper, to be precise `ActiveSupport`. I've updated the answer with a slice implementation for Ruby

Comment: You have nothing to be sorry for. My comment reflected the fact that I don't know Rails. I deleted my comment and will detete this one as well.